# js slicing even number in array

Tags: javascript, slice

So, I have object which I am splitting, but it is leaving a comma in between.

I thought I would use slice to only select the even number position to ignore the comma:

```
alert(sample); // first_name|^&|last_name|^&|

   var test = sample.split('|^&|');
```

Giving:  `first_name,last_name`

However, the comma is counted as an array and giving me a headache.

So, I thought I would use slice to select only the [0], [2], [4] and so on, thus ignoring the comma.

How do I select only the even number? (`var test = sample.split(',').slice(?);`)?

Comment: What does the sample look like? If you split on the comma it shouldn't give you a comma in the array.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I am actually splitting a combination of symbols (`|^&|`). I updated the question.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but you may consider doing something like:
for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i=i+2){
     test = sample.split(',').slice(i);
}

Comment: every item in your array is not containing a comma. where do you see the comma in `test`??

Comment: How are you using `test`? If you convert an array to a string, it creates a comma-delimited string.

Comment: Show the initial data input. This isn't making a lot of sense. there is no comma in `sample`

Comment: There's no jquery code here, just plain Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any commas in `test` elements

```
sample = 'first_name|^&|last_name|^&|';

test = sample.split('|^&|');

alert( test[ 0 ] ); // first_name

alert( test[ 1 ] ); // last_name
```

The only issue you may have is that as there is a trailing separator `|^&|` in `sample` you also have an empty element at the end of the array...

```
alert( test[ 2 ] ); // (empty string)
```

...that you may get rid of with just

```
test.pop(); // removes the last item of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) takes a string and splits into an array. If you use `sample.split('|^&|')`, it should split on all occurrences of `'|^&|'`.

```
var sample = "foo|^&|bar";
var test = sample.split('|^&|');
console.log(test);
// Output: ["foo", "bar"]
// Access: test[0] === "foo", etc.
```

If you need to retrieve every even element of the array, slice might not be the best bet. Try using something like:

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  if ((i % 2) === 0)
    // do something with the element here
}
```